# Registering event handlers with JS and Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, event-handling

In my transition from the basics of Python (learned on the Coursera RICE course) to the Javascript ones, I'm trying to register even handlers using the same paradigm people here have been helping me successfully converting.

In this example, both the timer and update handlers aren't running :

```js
//Globals
var message = "test message";
var positionX = 50;
var positionY = 50;
width = 500;
height = 500;
var interval = 2000;

//handler for text box
function update(text) {
  message = text;
}

//handler for timer
function tick() {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (width - 0) + 0);
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (height - 0) + 0);
  positionX = x;
  positionY = y;
}

//handler to draw on canvas
function draw(canvas) {
  ctx.font="20px Georgia";
  ctx.fillText(message,positionX,positionY);
}

//create a frame
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

//register event handlers
setInterval(tick, interval);
draw();

//start the frame and animation
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  Enter text here :
  <input type="text" onblur="update(this.value)">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Adding `canvas.addEventListener("draw", draw(), false);` and `canvas.addEventListener("update", update(), false);` didn't change anything.

Though, the only time it "worked" was when I added the `draw();` call inside the `tick();` function but it was keeping the text and duplicating it on screen randomly as the functions should work.

On a general note, do you guys think the current paradigm :

```
//Global state
//Handler for text box
//Handler for timer
//Handler to draw on canvas
//Create a frame
//Register event handlers
//Start the frame animation
```

is worth pursuing with JS and Canvas ?

Again, thanks for your time and help.

K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The draw function should be inside the tick function. If you want to stop the old text you need to clear the canvas before you draw the text again. SetInterval is ok for time over 100ms or so but if you plan to do full frame animation 60fps use `requestAnimationFrame`

I am personally not a fan of `setInterval` and use `setTimeout` instead. Also note that the times given for set interval and timeout are approximations only. Javascript is single threaded and if the timeout or interval occurs while code is running then the events will wait until the current execution is complete.

```js
"use strict";

//Globals
var message = "test message";
var positionX = 50;
var positionY = 50;
// constants
const width = 500;
const height = 500;
const interval = 2000;
if(typeof inputText !== "undefined"){
    inputText.value = message;
}

//handler for text box
function update(text) {
  message = text;
}

//handler for timer
function tick() {
  setTimeout(tick, interval);  // create the next timer event
  positionX = Math.floor(Math.random() * width);
  positionY = Math.floor(Math.random() * (height-20)); // 20 pixels of height to stop it disappearing 
  draw();

}

//handler to draw on canvas
function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
  var textWidth = ctx.measureText(message).width;
  ctx.fillText(message,Math.min(width - textWidth, positionX), positionY);
}

//create a context
const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
// set size befor get context as it is a little more efficient
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
// if the same font only need to set it once or after the canvas is resized
ctx.font="20px Georgia";


//start the animation
tick();
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  Enter text here :
  <input id="inputText" type="text" onblur="update(this.value)">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Blindman, actually I've followed your first advice by only adding the `draw();` call and `ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);` method inside the `tick();` function and it works perfectly !